# Como obter o valor da variável fora de método Future em Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo em um app de livros e estou preso na tela onde irá abrir o arquivo .pdf.

Preciso obter o caminho do diretório do celular usando o path_provider para enviar para o pdfviewer porém não consigo obter o caminho na variável fora do método. Porém se dou hot realod o caminho é obtido, mas quando volto a tela seleciono livro, baixo, e tento abrir o path fica null.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdf_viewer/flutter_pdf_viewer.dart';

class PdfScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final DocumentSnapshot document;

  PdfScreen(this.document);

  @override
  _PdfScreenState createState() => _PdfScreenState(document);
}

class _PdfScreenState extends State<PdfScreen> {

  final DocumentSnapshot document;

  _PdfScreenState(this.document);

  dynamic path;

  Future<dynamic> loadPdf() async{

    try{

     var  dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

     setState(() {
        path = "${dir.path}/${document["title"]}.pdf";
    }

      return **path**;

    }catch(e){
      print("ERRO: $e");
      return e;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    loadPdf();
    // path = "/data/data/br.com.apps.d.baixa_livros/app_flutter/${document["title"]}.pdf";
    print(path); // **Aqui printa null**


    return Container();
  }

}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Foi necessário usar o método loadPdf() dentro do iniState;

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no método `loadPdf()`, faça da seguinte forma:

```
Future<void> loadPdf() async {
    try{

        var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        setState(() {
            path = "${dir.path}/${document["title"]}.pdf";
        }

    }catch(e){
        print("ERRO: $e");
    }
}
```

O `setState()` informa para sua aplicação que o `Widget` deve ser reconstruído, ou seja, vai ser executado o bloco `Widget build(BuildContext context)` novamente e sua variável `path` já estará alimentada nesse segundo momento.

Comment: Não foi possível adicionar async, da erro no build porque precisaria ser do tipo Future.

Comment: @djalmafreestyler Falha minha, corrigi a 1ª Saída, faltou apenas por um `Future<void>`. Desconsidere a 2ª Saída, não está bem elaborada, é que eu estava sem o Flutter para testar.

Comment: Usei como você orientou, na verdade já tinha testado assim, na console imprime primeiro um nulo e depois imprime diversas vezes o caminho, com o setState dentro ou fora do try catch.

Comment: @djalmafreestyler É como expliquei abaixo do 1º exemplo, o `setState()` faz com que o `Widget` seja reconstruído, logo como sua variável está sendo printada no `build()` ela vai ser exibida sempre que o seu `widget` for reconstruído... Você pode contornar isso usando alguns patterns como BLoC, mas é algo mais avançado.

Comment: Resolvido, precisava usar o método getPdf no iniState. Obrigado de qualquer forma Matheus.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, a parte que está riscada ainda é relevante? Não seria o caso de removê-la e deixar a resposta mais limpa? Qualquer coisa, ainda dá para [consultar no histórico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/371086/2), mas creio que a intenção em por os `<strike>` era mostrar a irrelevância dessa parte da resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é isso mesmo, deixei a **2º SAÍDA** taxada como uma forma de dizer que ela não é a melhor forma a ser utilizada. Farei os ajustes para deixar a resposta melhor organizada.